# draw points using matplotlib.pyplot [[x1,y1],[x2,y2]]

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to draw graph using a list of `(x,y)` pairs instead of using two lists, one of X's and one of Y's. Something like this:

```
a = [[1,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,2]]
plt.plot(a, 'ro')
```

Rather than:

```
plt.plot([1,3,4,5], [2,3,4,2])
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 66):

You can do something like this:

```
a=[[1,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,2]]
plt.plot(*zip(*a))
```

Unfortunately, you can no longer pass 'ro'. You must pass marker and line style values as keyword parameters:

```
a=[[1,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,2]]
plt.plot(*zip(*a), marker='o', color='r', ls='')
```

The trick I used is [unpacking argument lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Comment: I usually use `plt.plot(*np.transpose(a))` (where I've called `import numpy as np`), which is equivalent to what you've suggested.

Comment: that unpacking is useful

Answer (score 11):

If you are using numpy array you could extract by axis:

```
a = array([[1,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,2]])
plot(a[:,0], a[:,1], 'ro')
```

For lists or lists you'll need some helper, like:

```
a = [[1,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,2]]
plot(*sum(a, []), marker='o', color='r')
```

Answer (score 9):

**list comprehensions**

I highly suggest the liberal application of list comprehensions. Not only are they terse and powerful, they tend to make your code very readable.

Try something like this:

```
list_of_lists = [[1,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,2]]    
x_list = [x for [x, y] in list_of_lists]
y_list = [y for [x, y] in list_of_lists]

plt.plot(x_list, y_list)
```

Argument unpacking should be avoided. It is ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Write a helper function.

Here is a longish version, but I am sure there is a trick to compress it.

```
>>> def helper(lst):
    lst1, lst2 = [], []
    for el in lst:
        lst1.append(el[0])
        lst2.append(el[1])
    return lst1, lst2

>>> 
>>> helper([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
([1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6])
>>>
```

Also add this helper:

```
def myplot(func, lst, flag):
    return func(helper(lst), flag)
```

And call it like so:

```
myplot(plt.plot, [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]], 'ro')
```

Alternatively you could add a function to an already instantiated object.